# Not having permission in /usr/share/applications/

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I was trying to create a new document in /usr/share/applications/ location, however, even though I have logged in with root user, I don't have permissions to create a new document or a new folder in this location.

Similarly, I am unable to delete, cut or edit any of the items.

Could you anyone please let me know the steps to create a new document in this folder?

[image]

Comment: *"I have logged in with root user"* Ubuntu is configured by default not to allow this. What is your end goal? there may be a better way to achieve it (for example using `~/.local/share/applications` instead)

Comment: I was just curious to know like why is it greyed out? I have recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through different blogs, I came to know that we don't have permissions to read and write in `/usr/share/applications` location.

Then I did the following:

1. Open the same location with in terminal.
2. Type `sudo touch <filename>.desktop` to create a new file. (enter the sudo password)
3. Type `sudo nano <filename>.desktop` to edit the file. (enter the sudo password)
4. Type `sudo -rm -rf <filename>.desktop` to delete the file. (enter the sudo password).

The above following steps helped me in creating and editing a new file in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Users don't have write access to `/usr/share/applications`:

```
$ ll /usr/share/applications
total 900
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 12288 Jul 18 06:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 343 root root 12288 Jun 30 09:29 ../
```

If you want to create a document there try:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/mydoc.txt
```

Add a few lines and save it. Then check that it is there:

```
$ ll /usr/share/applications/mydoc.txt

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 149 Jul 22 11:24 /usr/share/applications/mydoc.txt

$ cat /usr/share/applications/mydoc.txt

Test for writing into /usr/share/applications/mydoc.txt
For: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160114/not-having-permission-in-usr-share-applications
```